# Using websockets in telnet server in Python3

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I have been working on a game server written in python3. My goal is to keep the communication options on it very open so that multiple different clients can easily connect. Currently all communication has been through telnet using miniboa. I would like to have the option to allow for web based clients as well. It seems like the easiest option for that would be to allow websocket connections. I have been playing around with websockify which works, however I would prefer to not use a proxy if possible because then all the connections appear to come from the proxy. Ideally what I would like is something that I can put into my telnet server to recognize a websocket handshake request (as compared to the regular requests), return the proper handshake, then keep the connection going so the commands being sent/recieved through telnet and websockets are the same. I haven't been able to find anything that allows me to do this automatically so I have been experimenting around with writing my own code to recognize a websocket handshake and reply with a corresponding handshake. I have looked at many other posts and examples, epecially [python websocket handshake (RFC 6455)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152290/python-websocket-handshake-rfc-6455) which I modified and converted to the following test program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from miniboa import TelnetServer
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

clientlist = []


def client_connects(client):
    clientlist.append(client)


def client_disconnects(client):
    clientlist.remove(client)

def process_clients():
    for client in clientlist:
        if client.active and client.cmd_ready:
            total_cmd = client.get_command()
            print("incoming = {}" .format(total_cmd))
            if total_cmd.find(" ") != -1: # breaking apart incoming command
                cmd, cmd_var = total_cmd.split(" ", 1)
            else:
                cmd = total_cmd
                cmd_var = ""
            if cmd == "Sec-WebSocket-Key:":
                GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                cmd_var = cmd_var + GUID
                encoded = cmd_var.encode('utf-8')
                response_key = b64encode(sha1(encoded).digest())
                websocket_answer = (
                    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
                    'Upgrade: websocket',
                    'Connection: Upgrade',
                    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
                )
                handshake = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)
                client.handshakestr = handshake
            if cmd == "Upgrade:":
                print("Sending handshake:")
                print(client.handshakestr)
                print("End of Handshake")
                client.send(client.handshakestr)

server = TelnetServer(port=6112, on_connect=client_connects, on_disconnect=client_disconnects)

while True:
    process_clients()
    server.poll()
```

which seems to get me past the initial handshake but then it immediately drops. From the output it looks like the browser is expecting something further but I can't figure out what. For a client I am using the following code on firefox 29.0 I downloaded from http://opiate.github.io/SimpleWebSocketServer/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


  function init()
  {
    document.myform.url.value = "ws://localhost:8000/"
    document.myform.inputtext.value = "Hello World!"
    document.myform.disconnectButton.disabled = true;
  }

  function doConnect()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(document.myform.url.value);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("connected\n");
    document.myform.connectButton.disabled = true;
    document.myform.disconnectButton.disabled = false;
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("disconnected\n");
    document.myform.connectButton.disabled = false;
    document.myform.disconnectButton.disabled = true;
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("response: " + evt.data + '\n');
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('error: ' + evt.data + '\n');

    websocket.close();

    document.myform.connectButton.disabled = false;
    document.myform.disconnectButton.disabled = true;

  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("sent: " + message + '\n'); 
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    document.myform.outputtext.value += message
    document.myform.outputtext.scrollTop = document.myform.outputtext.scrollHeight;

  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);


   function sendText() {
        doSend( document.myform.inputtext.value );
   }

  function clearText() {
        document.myform.outputtext.value = "";
   }

   function doDisconnect() {
        websocket.close();
   }


</script>

<div id="output"></div>

<form name="myform">
<p>
<textarea name="outputtext" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<textarea name="inputtext" cols="50"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<textarea name="url" cols="50"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name=sendButton value="Send" onClick="sendText();">
<input type="button" name=clearButton value="Clear" onClick="clearText();">
<input type="button" name=disconnectButton value="Disconnect" onClick="doDisconnect();">
<input type="button" name=connectButton value="Connect" onClick="doConnect();">
</p>


</form>
</html>
```

So does anyone know either:
1. an easier way to use websockets with my telnet server?
2. what is wrong with my attempts at responding to a websocket connection?
3. if I should give up and settle for using a proxy with web connections?

Answer (score 0):

Tornado has a nice compliant [WebSocket handler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/websocket.html). You can use that, or use it [for reference](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py) when building yours.